# Avoid onresize and orientationchange both fires

Tags: javascript

In my existing application I am handling two events, one for change in orientation for mobile and onresize for desktop. unfortunately both events get fire.

I am trying to fire only one function whenever there is any change in device orientation or on browser resize. I want something like the example given below. Or Suggest me whatever I am missing here.

```
(function() {
  var getEvent = function() {
    event = window.ondeviceorientation || window.onresize;
    return event;
  };
  document.addEventListener(getEvent, function() {
    console.log("Size changed");
  }, false);

})();
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/kalayewapi/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetEvent is a function...

```
function() {
 var getEvent = function() {
    event = window.ondeviceorientation ? "deviceorientation" :  "resize";
    return event;
 };
 document.addEventListener(getEvent(), function() { //<---
  console.log("Size changed");
 }, false);

})();
```

And addEventListener requires a string, so you need to create a string. Shortified:

```
document.addEventListener(window.ondeviceorientation ? "deviceorientation" :  "resize", function() {
  console.log("Size changed");
 }, false);
```

This makes your code work but it *either* fires on deviceorientation *or* on resize. So you may want this:

```
function callable(){};
document.addEventListener("deviceorientation",callable);
document.addEventListener("resize",callable);
```